# How to iterate through a joined table with multiple results?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, join

I have 3 tables, `USER`, `ENTRY` (for entered products, not necessary to create a PRODUCT table), and `USER_COLLECTION`, which is a table inbetween `USER` and `ENTRY`, because an entry can have multiple users.

Basically:

User = `USERID | USER_NAME`

Entry = `ENTRYID | ENTRY_NAME | ENTRYPRICE | ENTRY_DATE`

Collection = `COLLECTIONID | ENTRYID | USERID`

I have a table with users that persist throughout the project. They can create entries (which is usually some kind of product with a price) and they can link multiple users to a certain entry (which can be selected from a list, hence the users persist throughout the project).

So for instance, my tables look like this:

```
User
--------------------------
user_id   |   user_name
--------------------------
   1      |    'FOO'
   2      |    'BAR'
   3      |    'FOOBAR'


ENTRY
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
entryid  |   entry_name     |  entry_price |      entry_date     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
   0     |    'Banana'      | 2.50         |  12/12/2012


COLLECTION
---------------------------------------
collectionid |   entryid    |  userid     
----------------------------------------
   0         |    1         | 1
   1         |    1         | 2
   2         |    1         | 3
```

I have a Banana, with a price of 2.50 and 3 users linked to it, Foo, Bar and Foobar.

Now, I want to use this in my app and get the data; except I don't know where to start. I tried selecting the entry data, using that id to loop through the collection data, but that would mean I have two cursors open and it wouldn't work. Tried creating a join but I couldn't really make a good one, mainly because:

```
JOIN
---------------------------------------
collectionid |   entryname |  username
----------------------------------------
   0         |    Banana   | FOO
   1         |    Banana   | BAR
   2         |    Banana   | FOOBAR
```

I can't iterate through this, because I would create multiple of the same entry objects in my Android code...

Hope I'm being clear on this.

```
if (cursor2.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Item i = new Item(<GET STUFF FROM CURSOR>);
        i.addUser(new Person(<GET STUFF FROM CURSOR>)));
        Log.d("TAG", i.getUsersPaying().size() + "");
    } while (cursor2.moveToNext());
}
```

If I use this, I create mulitple instances of Item i. They'll all be Banana, whilst I should only have 1 item Banana, with multiple users added to it.

Comment: why is `COLLECTION.collectionId` not incrementing? shouldn't it autoincrement?

Comment: Error on my part. Editing now

Comment: your join data looks like i would expect. it says that Foo, Bar, and Foobar have (bought?) a Banana. a cursor would hit each row in turn and you process that row. what do you expect to see? (maybe i'm missing something here)

Comment: When requesting help with SQL queries, you should give an example of the format you'd like to get the data.  Do you want only 1 record per entryname and not care about linked users?  Are you only interested in getting a specific users entrys back?

Comment: Edited my post again. Basically, I want the join I have in my post, but I want to iterate through it WITHOUT having multiple "Banana" items.

Comment: I also don't know the proper way to join the 3 tables together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you might want to consider returning the IDs from your tables in your join query.  Things would be a little easier if you returned the `entryid` column.

Just make a `Map<Integer, Item>` to store items that you have seen already in your loop.  As you examine each cursor, check the map to see if you already have an instance.  If you don't, just make a new one and insert it.

Let's assume your query results are:

```
JOIN
----------------------------------------------------
collectionid |   entryname |   entryname |  username
----------------------------------------------------
   0         |    1        |    Banana   | FOO
   1         |    1        |    Banana   | BAR
   2         |    1        |    Banana   | FOOBAR
   2         |    2        |    Apple    | FOOBAR
```

You can modify your code as follows:

```
Map<Integer, Item> items = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();
if (cursor2.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        int itemId = cursor2.getInt(1);
        Item i;
        if (items.containsKey(itemId))
            i = items.get(itemId);
        else
        {
            i = new Item(<GET STUFF FROM CURSOR>);
            items.put(itemId, i);
        }
        i.addUser(new Person(<GET STUFF FROM CURSOR>)));
        Log.d("TAG", i.getUsersPaying().size() + "");
    } while (cursor2.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: your HashMap is useless if you don't add created items to it ;)

Comment: Did the trick. You've opened up a world for me, as well. Gonna spend a few hours in the future to optimize my database...

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain a dictionnary of your entities which are already loaded in memory. For instance in a background fragment which would be retained.

Basically you would do:

```
Item i = cacheFragment.createOrGetEntry( cursor.getLong( ENTRY_ID_COLUMN_INDEX ) );
Person p = cacheFragment.createOrGetPerson( cursor.getLong( PERSON_ID_COLUMN_INDEX ) );
```

Of course, your query must also return the IDs of all the rows you need (entryId and personId). But a join query is the way to do it efficiently, so keep what you did about that and just add the two missing ID columns.

a createOrGetPerson method would look like:

```
public Person createOrGetPerson(long id) {
    Entry<Long, Person> p = personDictionnary.get( id ); // can be a HashMap or even better, a SparseArray
    if (p==null) {
      p = new Person(id);
      personDictionnary.put(p); // Remember it for next time
    }
    return p;
}
```

You should also have a look at data persistence frameworks or ORM frameworks which are made to deal with this kind of problem (e.g. Hibernate, even though I don't know if that is working with Android).